# Generic PostAsync method in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a method that will make `PostAsync` calls to my API. How do I define it so that it can receive one type of object and return another. When I define it with `T`, it's assuming the parameter and output are of the same kind.

```
public async Task<T> PostAsync<T>(string url, T param)
{
   HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(param), Encoding.UTF8);
   content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

   var response = await _client.PostAsync(url, content);
   if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
       throw new Exception();

   json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
}
```

I call this method and send `DomainObjectA` and expect to receive a `DomainObjectB`:

```
var myObjectA = new DomainObjectA
{
   FirstName = "John",
   LastName = "Doe"
};
var myObjectB = await PostAsync<DomainObjectB>("https://example.com/api/dosomething", myObjectA);
```

How do I specify both the parameter and the output object types?

Comment: Add a second generic type paramete so it's `PostAsync<TRequest,TResponse>`

Comment: BTW, you should add `Accept: application/json` to your `HttpRequestMessage` too, not just for your request's `Content-Type` header.

Comment: Also, you need to check _not only_ that the response status is `200-299` (or whatever your web-service's docs say to expect) but also that the response `Content-Type` is also `application/json`, as opposed to `text/html` or similar and handle those cases gracefully. Getting HTML responses is common for things like 404 errors - misconfigured webservers (and domain-parking...) are everywhere.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for all the help/advice. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I’ve got more of you want it - like, guidance on DTO design, why immutable types should be preferred over property-setters, the importance of *not* using entity types as DTOs, and why you don’t need to write this code at all if you use Swagger and NSwag client code-gen…

Comment: You are looking for something like https://github.com/microsoft/BikeSharing360_MobileApps/blob/master/src/BikeSharing.Clients.Core/DataServices/Base/IRequestProvider.cs